# How to get value of a Firebase object with a wildcard in the path interior?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase noobie so excuse whatever.

An app has a hierarchy of `containers` and `widgets`. Each ID is unique for its type (ie `widgetID`s are all unique).

Paths look like: `containers/<id>/widgets/<id>`

To access a single widget `widgetID` of container `containerID`, I use:

```
NSString *ref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"containers/%@/widget/%@", containerID, widgetID];
FIRDatabaseReference *containers = [fb child:ref]
[[fb child:ref] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) ...
```

To access all the widgets of container `containerID`, I use:

```
NSString *ref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"containers/%@/widgets", containerID];
[[fb child:ref] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) ...
```

Other parts of the app can move widgets. How can I access a specific widget whose ID I know that got moved? What I'd like to do is:

```
NSString *ref = @"containers/*/widget/123";
[[fb child:ref] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) ...
```

Obviously that won't work. Is the only solution to request every container and every widget for each, then fire something off in the deepest block if all matches? [Note: there are a lot of `containers`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to do what amounts to creating another index of all widgets so that you can query them all by their unique id.  Yes, this is data duplication, and yes, this is common for NoSQL type databases.  The structure of your data should suit the types of queries you want to perform on it.

So, you could add `/widgets/[wid]` where `wid` is your unique widget id.  That location could either entirely duplicate the data in `/container/[cid]/widgets/[wid]`, or just contain a reference there (requiring two queries).  Or any other mechanism that gets you the ability to query the way you want.

Comment: Looks like I'll be doing this more or less - others want me to have a single entry with an index of wid -> cid. Your answer was a big help - thanks!